# Failed to open backend connection: -98 (Address already in use) when I initial the MariaDB luster

Tags: mariadb

I have three nodes to set up mariadb cluster, and in the node1 to initial the Cluster:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --wsrep-new-cluster --user=root &
```

But get the below error:

```
[root@localhost my.cnf.d]# /usr/sbin/mysqld --wsrep-new-cluster --user=root &
[2] 18158
[root@localhost my.cnf.d]# 2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Warning] Ignoring user change to 'root' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line

2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.19-MariaDB) starting as process 18158 ...
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so'
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 25.3.18(r3632) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using hardware acceleration.
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 1e13df0b-6dfa-11e7-8408-7780522cc5ab:-1
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_dir = /var/lib/mysql/; base_host = 192.168.8.101; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /var/lib/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.size = 128M; gcomm.thread_prio = ; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.segment = 0; gmcast.version = 0; pc.announce_timeout = PT3S; pc.checksum = false; pc.ignore_quorum = false
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140053204432640 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: -1, protocol version: -1
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: 'wsrep-new-cluster' option used, bootstrapping the cluster
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: gcomm thread scheduling priority set to other:0 
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk successfully
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: (1e0cac5c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: (1e0cac5c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: bootstrapping new group 'openstack'
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [Note] WSREP: start_prim is enabled, turn off pc_recovery
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [ERROR] WSREP: Address already in use
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 98: error while trying to listen 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567?socket.non_blocking=1', asio error 'Address already in use': 98 (Address already in use)
     at gcomm/src/asio_tcp.cpp:listen():810
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():208: Failed to open backend connection: -98 (Address already in use)
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1380: Failed to open channel 'openstack' at 'gcomm://192.168.8.101,192.168.8.102,192.168.8.103': -98 (Address already in use)
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Address already in use
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://192.168.8.101,192.168.8.102,192.168.8.103) failed: 7
2017-07-21 18:24:23 140055716542656 [ERROR] Aborting
```

---

**EDIT-1**

```
netstat -a | grep 4567
```

get nothing.

Comment: to state the obvious: looks to me like there is already something else listening on port 4567. anything else on your system that might use the port ? what does `netstat -a` say ?

Comment: See my edit-1, I use netstat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I solved this issue:

use `ps` to check the mysql process:

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
```

get the below information:

```
mysql     17864  1.2 15.5 5263724 2535004 pts/0 Sl   17:51   0:46 /usr/sbin/mysqld --wsrep-new-cluster --user=root
root      18191  0.0  0.0 112644   952 pts/0    S+   18:55   0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld
```

Then I kill the mysql:

```
kill -s 9 17864
```

And now use the `/usr/sbin/mysqld --wsrep-new-cluster --user=root &` works normal.

Comment: Good job aircraft.